# Instagram: Video.object_from_dictionary(version_info) error

Tags: python, api, instagram

I have a problem with python-library (https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram)

```
    user_id = 'MY_USER_ID'
    access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'
    api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
    instagram_media, next_ = api.tag_recent_media(count=6, tag_name='MY_TAG')
```

I received an error on line (instagram/models.py)

```
new_media.videos[version] = Video.object_from_dictionary(version_info)
```

The error is:`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

Tip: if all media are **images** (instead of **video**) the library will work perfectly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the last undocumented change performed in the instagram API.
Have a look to those forks that have fixed this issue.
I maintain this fork up to date: https://github.com/MabrianOfficial/python-instagram